# How do I switch to a new branch in the same branch without retaining the commits from the previous push?

Tags: git

I cloned a repo and checkout to branch featureA. I am working on branch featureA and push two commits.

Then I switch to featureB and want to push two new commits, but the commits in featureA are part of featureB. How do I switch to a new featureB branch and start "afresh" that was the state before I pushed two commits?

Comment: featureA is two commits ahead of the master. Did you push the two commits in featureB?

Answer (score 1):

> Then I switch to featureB and want to push two new commits, but the commits in featureA are part of featureB. How do I switch to a new featureB branch and start "afresh" that was the state before I pushed two commits?

if you would just *switch* to featureB, the commits in featureA wouldn't be there. However, the thing you've probably done is that you've branched featureB from featureA, in which case the commits would be there, too. You'll need to branch from master instead. In that case featureB wouldn't know about featureA.

Switching branches is done with:

`git checkout featureB`

while branching from somewhere (creating new branch) can be done with, among other things,

`git checkout -b featureB`

So first switch to master and then branch featureB from there:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b featureB
```

Comment: You can combine as well: `git checkout -b featureB master`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have merged your commits from branch `featureA` to `master`, then you have to revert your changes from `master` and checkout to a new branch `featureB`. I am assuming that you are in your master branch in your local.

```
1. git revert <commit ID> -m <Parent number>
2. git push origin master
3. git checkout -b featureB
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

You want `git checkout -b featureB master`, or similar.

#### Long

One of the many things to learn about Git is that Git is not really about *branches*.  Git is really about *commits*.  Branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—are just the method by which you, and Git, *find* commits.

Let's draw your existing situation.  Drawing a graph of the set of existing commits is a good exercise and you should do it often.

> I cloned a repo ...

When you first clone some existing repository, you get all of its *commits*.  Each commit has some big ugly hash ID, unique to that commit.  Every Git repository everywhere uses the *same* hash ID for those specific commits.

When you do this `git clone`, right at the start, you *don't* get *any* of the other Git's branches.  But you don't need them, because Git isn't about branches.  You just need some *names* so that you can find the commits.  So your Git takes their *branch* names, and saves them in your repository as your *remote-tracking* names, such as `origin/master` and `origin/develop`.  That is, your Git remembers *their* branch names, as *your* remote-tracking names.

The last step of the `git clone` process is that your Git creates, in your repository, one branch name.  That one branch name has to point to one of the *commits* you got from their Git.  Which of these commits should your Git use?  There are probably hundreds or thousands of commits; how will your Git pick the *right* one?  You can tell it, but the usual default is: *Use the name `origin/master`, which we got from the other Git repository at `origin`, to pick out the commit; make my new branch name `master` identify that same commit.*

So, if they have a series of commits ending at some hash ID `H`, we can draw it like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master, origin/master
```

The last of their `master` commits is this hash `H`.  (Its actual hash is some big ugly string of letters and digits—we're just using `H` for short.)  That commit stores inside it the hash ID of some other, earlier commit, which we'll call `G`.  Commit `G` stores inside it the hash ID of some other earlier commit, which we'll call `F`.

When you run `git log`, Git starts by reading the name `master` to find hash `H`.  Then it shows you commit `H`.  Then it uses commit `H` to find hash `G`, and shows you commit `G`.  It uses that to find `F`, and shows you `F`.  This repeats all the way back to the *very first commit ever*.  That first commit *doesn't* point back any further, because it can't, and that's how Git knows how to stop.

> ... and checkout to branch featureA.

There are two possibilities here: `featureA` existed on `origin` before, or it didn't.  Your own Git doesn't have a `featureA` yet—it only has a `master`—so if you run:

```
git checkout featureA
```

your own Git would normally just say *I don't have a `featureA`*.  But instead of doing that, your Git will check through your `origin/*` names, to see if you have an `origin/featureA`.  If so, your Git will find the commit that your `origin/featureA` names, and create your own new `featureA`, pointing to that commit.

If you *don't* have an `origin/featureA` either, then you have to tell your Git to *create* `featureA` now, using either `git branch` or `git checkout -b`.  You might tell your Git: *Make new name `featureA`, pointing to the same commit that my current branch name `master` points to.*  This gives you:

```
...--F--G--H  <-- master, featureA, origin/master
```

Now that you have *two* branch names (plus all the remote-tracking names `origin/*`), we need some way to remember *which branch name your Git is using*.  To do that, we'll attach the special name `HEAD`, in all uppercase like this, to one of the two branch names.

Note that the two branch names currently both point to the *same* commit hash ID (`H` in this example)!  That's perfectly fine.  It just means that both branches end at commit `H`.

> I am working on branch featureA and push two commits.

Presumably, what you mean here is that you created two new commits, then used `git push` to get the other Git repository, over at `origin`, to take your two new commits and create or update *its* `featureA` name.

Let's draw this create-two-new-commits process.  We start, as we saw, with:

```
...--F--G--H  <-- master, featureA (HEAD), origin/master
```

First, you made one new commit (in the usual way).  That one new commit got a new, unique hash ID, different from the hash ID of every other commit everywhere in the world.<sup>1</sup>  We'll just call it `I` though, and draw it in:

```
...--F--G--H  <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I   <-- featureA (HEAD)
```

Note how new commit `I` points back to existing commit `H`, and that the *name* `featureA` now points to `I` instead of `H`.  No existing commit has changed!  You just added a *new* commit, with a new hash ID, and *moved the branch name*.  This is how branches grow, in Git.

Then you made a second new commit:

```
...--F--G--H  <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- featureA (HEAD)
```

Last, you used `git push` to send the new commits, `I` and `J`, to the other Git over at `origin`.  You asked that Git to set, in its repository, the name `featureA` to point to commit `J`.  Given that it said *OK, I have done that* your Git then created your `origin/featureA` to remember that *their* Git, at `origin`, now has a `featureA`:

```
...--F--G--H  <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- featureA (HEAD), origin/featureA
```

> Then I switch to featureB and want to push two new commits, but the commits in featureA are part of featureB. How do I switch to a new featureB branch and start "afresh" that was the state before I pushed two commits?

Now that we have all these graph drawings, the answer is much clearer.  We just need to create the new *name* `featureB` such that it points to existing commit `H`, the same one that `master` and `origin/master` name.

The two normal ways to create a new branch name are to use `git branch` or `git checkout -b`.  The difference is that `git branch` creates the name and then stops, while `git checkout -b` creates the name, then does a `git checkout` on the name.  Since you want the `git checkout` step as well, it makes sense to use the combined command—but let's draw it out as separate steps.

By default, *both* commands create the *new* label—the new branch name—pointing to the *current commit*.  Git finds the current commit using the special name `HEAD`.  If that name is attached to a branch name, as it usually is, Git follows the arrow coming out of the branch name to find the commit.

Right now, `HEAD` is attached to `featureA`, and `featureA` points to commit `J`.  So if you just create a branch name with `git branch featureB`, the new name would point to commit `J`.  But you'd like it to point to commit `H`.

You can easily tell `git branch` to use *any existing commit*.  All you need is its hash ID, or any name that points to that commit.  So you can run `git log` and find the actual hash ID of commit `H` and type that in—which is kind of hard to do though cut-and-paste makes it easier to get it right—or you can just use any of the names that still point to commit `H`, such as `master` or `origin/master`:

```
git branch featureB master
```

for instance.  This produces:

```
...--F--G--H  <-- master, featureB, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- featureA (HEAD), origin/featureA
```

Note that `HEAD` is still attached to `featureA`, which still points to commit `J`.

Now that `featureB` exists, we can use `git checkout` to switch to it.  This replaces your *index* (which we haven't mentioned here as this answer is all about branch names) and *working tree* (which again we haven't really mentioned here) with the contents of commit `H` while attaching the name `HEAD` to the name `featureB`:

```
...--F--G--H  <-- master, featureB (HEAD), origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- featureA, origin/featureA
```

Your *current commit* is now `H`; your *current branch name* is now `featureB`; and you're ready to make new commits, which will cause `featureB` to advance to include the new commits you make.

---

<sup>1</sup>This uniqueness is *why* Git hash IDs are so big and ugly.  They really *are* this unique in practice, but they really only *have* to be unique across all Git repositories that ever "meet each other".  However, since SHA-1 is considered insecure and "broken", Git is moving to SHA-256, to help maintain this "unique across all commits on Earth and anywhere else in the solar system or galaxy in the future" promise.

Comment: Maybe for the TLDR part just add `git checkout master && git checkout -b featureB` which should be the same but is more transparent whats happening? Love the effort you put in here :)

Comment: Thank you so much, really helped me understand what's happening.